# WPF change ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate in code behind

Tags: wpf, itemtemplate, itemspanel

I have the following list in XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewBack"
          Margin="3"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource IconListPanelTemplate}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconListDataTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

Now I would like to be able to change the ItemsPanel and ItemTemplate from the List to the Grid version. I've tried this using the following code:

```
ListViewBack.ItemsPanel = Resources["IconGridPanelTemplate"] as ItemsPanelTemplate;
ListViewBack.ItemTemplate = Resources["IconGridDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

But nothing happens when excecuted.

Any idea's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your obvious problem is that you are using `Resources[]` instead of `FindResource()`.  In general, `Resources[]` will only work if your resource is in the `this.Resources` dictionary, and not elsewhere.

This is how I would rewrite your two lines of code:

```
ListViewBack.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)ListViewBack.FindResource("IconGridPanelTemplate");
ListViewBack.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)ListViewBack.FindResource("IconGridDataTemplate");
```

Acutally I would be more likely to use triggers or use DynamicResource and swap resource dictionaries for this purpose, but that's another story.

Note that I called `ListViewBack.FindResource()` instead of just `FindResource()`.  This is in case where IconGridPanelTemplate is redefined in a resource dictionary below the UserControl level.  If this will never be possible, you can simply call `FindResource()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to style your ListView.View, not the ListView itself.
Check the documentation for the [ViewBase Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbase.aspx) for an example.